# Facebook : Upload mutiple photos for a single post from android application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have to **post** multiple photos to Facebook from Android application. 
Can anyone help me how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the Facebook Android SDK and integrate it into your application.

Then use [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/) link to be able to log in the user into your Facebook application, thereby acquiring a valid access token. Make sure to ask for the `publish_stream` permission.

Then you have to make the appropriate graph API call to upload photos. Calling general graph API is explained [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph/).

The method to post photos to a user's facebook is done using the `/{album-id}/photos`, `/{user-id}/photos` or directly to the user's wall through `/{user-id}/feed`. The appropriate endpoints are listed out [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference).

It would also help if you show what progress you have made in your attempt so far, but because it was a general question, this is a fairly general answer.

Comment: SalGad, Thanks for your help. I am able to post status with single image. But I have to upload multiple images for a single post. Do we have way to do this using 'feed'? or do we need to go for album creation? please suggest

Comment: Hi @SomeswarReddy the best way to do this will be album creation. It is the only way to do multiple photos together for a single post - though it will be different photos and can have one common caption for the album description etc.